# Add a new page to a resource in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Ok, This seem so simple that I feel kind of dumb for asking, yet I have seen other that asked something similar but no quite the same and their answers does not solve my problem. I have a resource called servicios.

resources :servicios, created the routes for the "default" actions that are in my controller: index, new, create, show, edit, update, destroy. However, I need another action which is **search** that should map to my view  where I'm going to implement an advance search.

How can I do that?

> Editing with new info
>   using this approach: resources :servicios, :collection => {:search => :get}
>   http://localhost:3000/servicios/search
>   I was getting error
>   ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ServiciosController#show
>   Couldn't find Servicio with ID=search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Rails 3 then the route definitions will look like

```
resources :servicios do
  collection do
    get :search
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
resources :servicios, :collection => {:search => :get}
```

Will route /servicios/search to `def search...end` in the servicios controller.

Or...

```
match 'search', :to => 'servicios#search'
```

Comment: I updated the question so you can see what i got. I'm interested in using the search method from the controller.

Comment: You usually have to restart the server after making changes to the routes file. Did you do that?